# Можно ли устроиться на работу прикладным программистом на C# человеку без опыта работы?

Tags: c#, работа

Я листал вакансии для поиска работы в Киеве по данному вопросу. Но практически все вакансии мне попадаются на программиста asp.net. Вакансий на прикладного программиста С# очень мало. Лично у меня нету желание заниматься веб программированием. Неужели сейчас сложно человеку найти работу, который хочет работать в прикладном программирование на С#?

Comment: куда же таких программистов прикладывать?)

Comment: Блин прям вопрос задали, который я и сам хотел задать, только руки не доходили, тоже ожидаю ответа)))

Comment: Думаю, следует ставить в альтернативу веб-разработке не "прикладное" программирование, а десктопное, мобильное и геймдев.

Comment: Сейчас надо брать что дают, максимально приближенное к желаемой области. Набираться опыта и параллельно развивать ту область, которой хотите заниматься. Может в процессе вообще пересмотрите свои взгляды и выберете вообще другое направление. Наберетесь опыта, и уже сможете выбирать из предложенного

Answer (score 1):

Я раньше писал на ASP.NET, потом перешёл на Windows Forms и вполне доволен этим. На мой взгляд, Web - это ад, причины описал johniek_comp. Мы, например, берём даже студентов-третьекурсников на работу, так что ищите и обязательно найдёте. Да, Web более востребован, но там меньше творчества и больше ковыряния в проблемах. Скорее всего, именно потому и более востребован, что охотников заниматься этим меньше.

Answer (score -1):

Прикладное? Не, не слышал...

Начнем с того что здесь одни велосипеды! Фотошоп написали, firefox написали, ОС хватает, что делать? Что писать? А вот насчет веба: здесь ещё не все написано и проекты как и их идеи рождаются по сотни в день, можно делать новое, улучшать старое! Это раз...

Во-вторых, веб - это не тебе не открыл IDE, написал код, запустил компилятор и программа готова, и сам не знаешь как оно работает и пусть работает, это наука, технология, здесь нельзя допустить ошибку, нужно знать многие другие вещи, от устройства протоколов, и до защиты приложений, иначе поломают ваши сайты 14-летние школьники :) Веб - это интересно! В то время и сложно, но оно того стоит если программирование твоя жизнь.

Comment: Что писать? Раз за разом находится, чего еще нового не хватает. Причем новое необязательно что-то высоконаучное, иногда это просто лучший вариант взаимодействия с пользователем или что-то еще. Бывает, что старые велосипеды совсем ржавеют и не успевают за развитием остального. И так далее. Веб-разработка может и интересно, но не нужно говорить типа "в моей области все круто, а в остальных никаких перспектив".

ЗЫ: а сколько еще всего не написанного в области игр, и в области ПО под коммуникаторы и планшеты (а так же в области игр под коммуникаторы и планшеты).

Comment: > веб - ... это наука, технология, здесь нельзя допустить ошибку, нужно знать многие другие вещи, от устройства протоколов, и до защиты приложений    

Простите, но в какой реальности вы живете? В той, где аццкие js-ниндзя от нечего делать по вечерам клепают патчи в ядро линукса, а десктопные программисты только и делают, что спрашивают на форумах, как сделать калькулятор на паскале?

Comment: @VioLet - ну не надо крайностей, не веб программисты тоже задают достаточное количество идиотских вопросов. Сфера тут тоже не причем. Лично я считаю что нужно все и что программирование востребовано и неважно прикладной программист, сис. программист, разработчик прикладного ПО и т.д. Нужно все.

И во всех сферах есть хорошие и плохие специалисты, так чт абсолютной истины здесь нет и быть не может.